# Trying to join 4 different tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I realized when trying to query a database I have that I needed to go through four different tables in order to retrieve the data I need. Unfortunately, my brain can not comprehend a JOIN query past two tables so I figured I would ask for help here... I would be very grateful if someone more knowledgeable could help me with that.

Basically, I am trying to figure out the email addresses of the contacts that have been contacted by specific addresses through our Email Marketing Automation Platform that is Mautic.

The way it works is that you have a table with all of the leads with an id and an email address.
You then have a table with every email that has been sent and from which address it has been sent but not to which lead it has been sent. Every email as its own id.

To know to which list of leads an email has been sent, I need to look into a third table that links emails' id to lists' id.

Finally, our fourth table is the list of leads' lists. This is how I can know which lead is part of which list.

So the idea is:

From every email id that has been sent under x@gmail.com, match it to the list of lead its been sent to and check for the leads' id that are inside this lead list. Then retrieve the email of each of these leads' id by looking at the leads table.

My end result should be an email address located in a table called 'ma_leads'

[image]

As you can see, each contact has an 'id'. 'id' that we can find in the table `ma_lead_lists_leads' under the column name 'lead_id'.

[image]

This table also has a column 'leadlist_id' which we are going to find in the table `ma_email_list_xref`

[image]

This table itself has a column named 'email_id' which we can finally find in `ma_emails` under the column name 'id'.

[image]

This table finally has a "from_address" column that is the filter I talked about initially.

I hope it makes sense. I tried a few JOIN statements but I always seem to make mistakes in the first line so I thought I would turn to this community hoping I can get nudged int he right direction.

Thank you for your time. And I'm obviously going to monitor this thread if any question pops up...

Comment: This is what I tried so far:

SELECT
    `ma_leads`.email
FROM
    `ma_leads` INNER JOIN `ma_lead_lists_leads` ON
        `ma_leads`.id = `ma_lead_lists_leads`.lead_id
    INNER JOIN `ma_email_list_xref` ON
        `ma_email_list_xref`.leadlist_id = `ma_lead_lists_leads`.lead_id
    INNER JOIN `ma_emails` ON
        `ma_emails`.id = `ma_email_list_xref`.email_id
WHERE
    `ma_emails`.from_address = 'yaniss@sweetspotpr.com'

Answer (score 0):

I'd use this :

```
select l.email 
from ma_leads l, ma_lead_lists_leads ll, ma_email_list_xref el, ma_emails l 
where l.id = ll.lead_id and ll.leadlist_id = el.leadlist_id and el.email_id = e.id and e.from_address = 'yaniss@sweetspotpr.com';
```

Comment: Hey thank you for taking the time to get back to me.

I am not sure how to use this, what are the "l" "ll" "el" you are referring to in your example?

Comment: @YanissIlloul these are aliases, to avoid writing again and again the name of the table.